# mysql select statement?

Tags: mysql, select

I have following MYSQL table

```
OrderId OrderItemId IsReceived
  1         21          0
  1         22          1
  2         31          1
  2         11          0
  2         21          0
  3         31          1
  3         12          1
```

- If `IsReceived` == 1, means this item is received.
- If `IsReceived` == 0, means this item is not received yet.

I want to know which order is completely received (All `orderItems` are received), what is the Mysql Query?

In this case, it will return an `OrderId`: 3  (because in the `orderId` 3, all order items are received)

Answer (score 7):

Here's one solution:

```
SELECT OrderId
FROM `IHaveFollowingMySQLTable`
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING MIN(IsReceived) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

And another

```
SELECT OrderId
  FROM  OrderItems
 GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING SUM(IsReceived) = COUNT(IsReceived)
```

But @Bill Karwin's answer is most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(tbl.OrderId) from your_table_name tbl where tbl.OrderId not in
(select distinct(tbl2.OrderId) from your_table_name tbl2 where tbl2.IsReceived=0)
```